# C++ copy constructor with object pointer as argument

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I'm still a bit shaky about C++'s copy and assignment constructors. So far what I have is in `A.hpp`:

```
class A {
private:
     char* str;
public:
     A(char* str);

     // strcpy str from other to this.
     A(const A& other);

     // free str in this, and strcpy str from other to this.
     A& operator=(const Type& other);
}
```

Assuming I have `A* a = new A(some_char_str);`
, I'm able to write `A b = *a;`, and `b` is a deep copy of `a`.
Now the problem is that I want the ability to write `A* b = new A(a);` So how can I specify a constructor that takes a pointer to `A` and create a new `A` on the heap?

Comment: Why not try it first?  If there is an error, let us know.  No need to suffer from "analysis paralysis".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well... I just felt like I'm an idiot... I'm think about the copy/assignment constructor thing too hard...

Comment: @fleetC0m don't be hard on yourself. At least you gave it some thought, which is more than a lot of people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well the brain fart... I just realized I can provide a constructor `A::A(const A* other)` myself without using copy/assignment constructor,
or just write `A* b = new A(*a);` as suggested in comment.

Comment: I think your original code had all of the necessary parts to perform what you requested.  That's why I ask that you try it first.

Comment: BTW, If `a` is a pointer to an `A`, you had all the pieces already done in your original code:  `A* newA = new A(*a);`  This will call your copy constructor (which you coded) -- no need for another constructor that takes a pointer to `A`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When I try `A* b = new A(*a);`, I got `error: no viable conversion from 'A *' to 'A'`. That is without the `A(const A* other);` constructor of course